# Javascript Rock, Paper, Scissors game

Tags: javascript

I have been working on this Rochambeau game in JavaScript and so far when I run it, it will prompt for user input but no matter what you input, the result is ALWAYS a tie. Here is my code:

```js
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
var computerChoice = Math.random();
if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
} else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
} else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
} console.log("Computer: " + computerChoice);

function compare(userChoice, computerChoice){
    if(userChoice === computerChoice){
        alert("The result is a tie!");
    }
    else if(computerChoice === "scissors"){
        alert("rock wins!");
        if(computerChoice === "paper"){
            alert("paper wins!");
            }
        }
    else if(computerChoice === "rock"){
        alert("rock wins!");
        if(computerChoice === "scissors"){
            alert("scissor wins!");
            }
        }
    else if(computerChoice === "rock"){
        alert("rock wins!");
        if(computerChoice === "paper"){
            alert("scissors wins!");
            }
        }
}
compare();
```

Any idea why this isn't running the rest of the conditions?

Comment: Your function is defined as `function compare(userChoice, computerChoice)` but you are not passing in anything `compare();`

Comment: your compare function takes 2 arguments, but when you call it, you don't pass any arguments. so they're both `undefined` and they tie

Comment: functions don't know your game, you should tell them what to compare....

Comment: You're overriding the random number `computerChoice` with the string "rock" which will cause the following comparison to fail.

Comment: I assume you debugged this. When you stopped at the first line of the `compare` function, what were the values of the parameters?

Comment: Okay so I called the function with the appropriate parameters. Now the result is always "rock wins!"

Answer (score 0):

You're not passing any parameters to the function. The parameters in the function will default to `undefined`. So `undefined === undefined` equals true. You should do this instead:

`compare(userChoice, computerChoice);`

Comment: Awesome downvote, care to explain why? As far as I'm concerned this solves OPs issue

Answer (score -1):

> compare();

Aren't you missing the parameters?